# UnicodeDecodeError - Issues concatenating multiple csv's from a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to concatenate (vertically) a bunch of csv files (approximately 50) which are all in the same folder, saved to my laptop, and they all have the same headers.

However, when I try to do this, I get the following error message:

> `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 2: invalid start byte`

I'm not too sure what is causing this.  Could it perhaps be there are some weird characters in the csv files?  For example, one of the values in column is `"rÊ¢ªºbþ0.32639"`.  There are a few anomalies like this littered throughout my datasets, I believe due to glitches with the measuring instrumentation.  Because of the massive amount of data and numerous csv files, going through and manually deleting each of these measurements is too time consuming and not an option.

My code thus far:

```
import pandas as pd    
import numpy as np    
import os    
import glob    
from datetime import datetime

os.chdir("PATH")    

# Use glob to match the pattern csv    
extension_EC1 = 'csv'    
all_filenames_EC1 = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension_EC1))]

# Combine all files in the list     
combined_EC1_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames_EC1])

# Export to csv    
combined_EC1_csv.to_csv("combined_csv_EC1", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

The error points to the concatenation line in the script.  I'm wondering maybe I need to encode them as utf8 before this somehow?  And ignore the errors?  I've looked at numerous threads here, and they seem to all encode when reading the csv.  I just couldn't get anything to work because nothing I found was making a list of all the csv files in a directory beforehand.  Also, I found some threads saying 
 to use `encoding='cp1252'`, however I don't know how to do that before concatenating them.

Anyways, any information or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  And some of the modules I imported are for previous parts of the code, I just can't get this specific part to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read_csv` method of pandas has a parameter called **encoding**. you can pass the encoding of your choice in the parameter an read the csv

For e.g if you wish to apply the **cp1252** encoding tothe csv files you can try this code out

```
import pandas as pd    
import numpy as np    
import os    
import glob    
from datetime import datetime

os.chdir("PATH")    

# Use glob to match the pattern csv    
extension_EC1 = 'csv'    
all_filenames_EC1 = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension_EC1))]

# Combine all files in the list in a single df, along the columns
#Change Axis value to 0 if the number of columns in the csv files are
# not the same across all the files.

combined_EC1_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f,encoding='cp1252') for f in all_filenames_EC1],axis=1)

# Export to csv    
combined_EC1_csv.to_csv("combined_csv_EC1", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: This. Some of the `.csv`s probably follow another encoding. If you are processing mutiple files you could wrap the `encoding='cp1252'` part in a `try: / except:` block.

Comment: Wow, okay awesome, it has worked for me!  Thanks so much for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Can you accept the answer and close the question then?